# Sorting strings in python doesnt work

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort this list `['a', '2%20q']` I hoped to see `['2%20q', 'a']` but the code below produces `['a', '2%20q']` (initial list left intact)

```
sorted(['a', '2%20q']) // output: ['a', '2%20q']
```

Comment: When I run the code on python 3.3 it outputs `sorted(['a', '2%20q'])
['2%20q', 'a']`

Comment: I get the correct output (`['2%20q', 'a']`) in 2.7.3 as well.

Comment: Not repeatable: `>>> sorted(['a', '2%20q'])
['2%20q', 'a']
`

Comment: What output do you get for this: `sorted(['1', 'a', '2', 'b', 'c'])`?

Comment: I notice you didn't post an actual transcript.  Is this exactly what you did, or did you have a list with those elements -- call it `x` -- and then you did `sorted(x)`, and then looked at `x` to see that it was the same?  [The point being that `sorted(x)` doesn't change `x` -- `x.sort()` does -- and so if you did `sorted(x)` expecting `x` to change, I can see why you would be confused.]

Comment: I get ['1', '2', 'a', 'b', 'c']

Comment: Then I agree with @DSM you changed something to x prior to sorting. I got confused by the way this question was presented

Comment: I noticed you wrote *"(initial list left intact)"*. That's what `sorted` is doing, it creates a sorted *copy* of the list ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)). If you want to modify the list in-place, you have to call its `.sort` method.

Comment: well I saw my mistake I was not assigning sorted() return thx a lot guys!

Comment: @FelixKling: I agree that's what's going on, but the OP explicitly said that "the code below", `sorted(['a', '2%20q'])`, produces the output `['a', '2%20q']`.  The only way this makes much sense is if the OP is wrong about his report.

Comment: You really shouldn't accept the the posted answer... it cannot be taken seriously. It don't understand why it got upvotes at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted(['a','2%20q'], key=lambda x: 0 if x == '2%20q' else 1)`

Comment: It does show, however, how to approach this problem. No data was given on the desired sorting method.

Comment: Agreed, what should we name this new sorting method?

Comment: 'Making myself indispensable' sort perhaps.